# Command not found on gitlab ci using cat

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cat, gitlab-api

I have a Gitlab job in which I get a value from a .txt file. This value (v100322.1) was written into the text file in a previous stage and passing by to the job through artifacts.
When I try to get value from the file with cat command I get this error on the pipeline:

```
$ $PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat build.txt)
+++ cat build.txt
++ $'=\377\376v100322.1\r'
bash: line 132: $'=\377\376v100322.1\r': command not found
```

And this is my YAML file for GitLab-CI:

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - trigger

.deploy_job_base:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - dotnet
  script:
    - $PACKAGE_VERSION="v100322.1"
    - ${PACKAGE_VERSION} > build.txt
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - build.txt
  allow_failure: false

deploy_job_sport:
  extends: .deploy_job_base

deploy_job_TestClient:
  extends: .deploy_job_base

# trigger GitLab API call
.trigger_base:
  stage: trigger
  script:
    - $PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat build.txt)
    - 'curl --include --fail --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form "PACKAGE_VERSION=$PACKAGE_VERSION" --form "ref=feature/1000" $GITLAB_BASE_URL/api/v4/projects/$APP_PROJECT_ID/trigger/pipeline'

trigger_sport:
  extends: .trigger_base
  variables:
    APP_PROJECT_ID: "2096"
  needs: [deploy_job_sport]
  dependencies:
    - deploy_job_sport

trigger_TestClient:
  extends: .trigger_base
  variables:
    APP_PROJECT_ID: "2110"
  needs: [deploy_job_TestClient]
  dependencies:
    - deploy_job_TestClient
```

Do you know which is the problem here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you assign to a variable in bash you do not need the preceeding `$`, so that should be removed from all your calls; $PACKAGE_VERSION="v100322.1" and $PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat build.txt) etc

Comment: If I remove $ char, I get that error:

$ PACKAGE_VERSION="test"
PACKAGE_VERSION=test : The term 'PACKAGE_VERSION=test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.

Comment: You appear to be using a GitLab runner on Windows, not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the syntax, you can always check it on a virtual box, or better, pull the docker image down that the job will be executed on, and test the script in there

(using `docker run -it ${JOB_DOCKER_IMAGE} /bin/bash` for instance).

I just tested your script and got this:
[image]

you can clearly see `bash` will not like the `$` in front of PACKAGE_VERSION and interpret it, like a command ...

But you can turn the script of `.deploy_job_base` into a one-liner like this:

[image]

you circumnavigate the need for defining a variable and just dump it in the `build.txt` file.